# Alternative to using `display:none` on different devices to stop functions firing

Tags: php, css

I'm currently using CSS media queries to hide things via `display:none;` for desktop and mobile. While this works fine for minor things I have a dashboard that has a large amount of functionality depending on the device.

At the moment using `display:none` means that the functions still fire and this puts huge strain on our hosting environment. It's currently taking 16s to load!

Is there an alternate way to only serve the content depending on the device? This way I can stop the desktop functions firing on mobile and vice versa.

Ideally a way of doing it in PHP would be ideal.

Comment: I'd make use of window.resize or ResizeObserver in js. That way you could check the same size that you wrote into your media query and add or remove that part from the DOM. I'm not a php guy, but it's just an idea that you could try :)

Comment: You'll need a js loader that will check the environment and make requests to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried:

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { ?>
```

This works really well as it stops ALL the functions firing and I can control whether the desktop of mobile function should fire.